# Printing the sublist in which the required number is found

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, loops

I have a list containing sublists and I want to search the first element of each sublist and then print the sublist where the element is found. My code is :

```
list = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]

for i in list:
    if (i[0])==6:
        print "Yes"
```

The program shows that I have found the element, but how can I print the list in which it is found? (`[6,7,8,9,10]`)

Comment: Print the list itself? `print "Yes", i `.

Comment: perhaps this might help you understand `for sublist in list` if found, `print sublist`

Comment: Do you mean searching for a sublist in a list? Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to print `i`. You are already utilizing that in your `for` loop:

```
for i in list:
    if (i[0])==6:
        print "Yes"
        print i
```

Outputs:

```
Yes
[6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]

for i in list:
    if (i[0])==6:
        print "Yes"
        print i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use closure-like method:

```
def find_list(list_of_list, item):
    def find_item(item):
        if item == list_[0]: 
            print('%i found in %r ' % (item, list_))
            return list_

    for list_ in list_of_list:
        found_list = find_item(item)
        if found_list:
            return found_list


>>> print(find_list([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]], 1))
1 found in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score -3):

```
my_list = [[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]

print [sub for sub in my_list if sub[0] == 6]
```

Comment: read carefully. from OP: `I want to search the first element of each sublist` this searches whole list and it prints list of list.

Comment: there is no reason to use list comprehension in this context. you are generating list of list.